# extract a variable value from the middle of a string

Tags: regex, powershell

I have been trying to figure out for quite sometime.  how do I get the PID value from the following string using powershell? I thought REGEX was the way to go but I can't quite figure out the syntax.
For what it is worth everything except for the PID will remain the same.

```
    $foo = <VALUE>I am just a string and the string is the thing. PID:25973. After this do that and blah blah.</VALUE>
```

I have tried the following in regex

```
[regex]::Matches($foo, 'PID:.*') | % {$_.Captures[0].Groups[1].value}
[regex]::Matches($foo, 'PID:*?>') | % {$_.Captures[0].Groups[1].value}
[regex]::Matches($foo, 'PID:*?>') | % {$_.Captures[0].Groups[1].value}
[regex]::Matches($foo, 'PID:*?>(.+).') | % {$_.Captures[0].Groups[1].value}
```

Comment: Can you show what regex you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your regex you'll want to indicate what's before and after the portion you're looking for.  `PID:.*` will find everything from the PID to the end of the string.

And to use a capture group you'll want to have some `(` and `)` in your regex, which defines a group.

So try this on for size:

```
[regex]::Matches($foo,'PID:(\d+)') | % {$_.Captures[0].Groups[1].value}
```

I'm using a regex of `PID:(\d+)`.  The `\d+` means "one or more digits".  The parentheses around that `(\d+)` identifies it as a group I can access using `Captures[0].Groups[1]`.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH for the line of code and the explanation of how it works.  That works perfectly, and you have also provided me with a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option. Basically it replaces everything with the first capture group (which is the digits after 'pid:':

```
$foo -replace '^.+PID:(\d+).+$','$1'
```